# When making a Linux fielsystem, what to pass for the user_namespace parameter for inode_init_owner

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a Linux filesystem driver, and found [this code](https://lwn.net/Articles/57371/) in a tutorial. From there, I came across [this modified version](https://gist.github.com/prashants/3496839) of the previous code, which makes it compile on 3.x kernels. However it seems that again the filesystem API has changed, and one of the functions (`inode_init_owner`) takes a new parameter. The new signature of this function (in `linux/fs.h`) is:

```c
void inode_init_owner(struct user_namespace *mnt_userns, struct inode *inode,
              const struct inode *dir, umode_t mode);
```

This `mnt_userns` parameter isn't given in the example code, and I can't seem to find any documentation for this function online whatsoever. I tried passing `NULL` for it, in case it would then just ignore it and revert to previous behaviour, but unsurprisingly this led to a crash (dereferencing NULL pointer).

What should this parameter be set to? What does it even mean? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to this, though I'm not sure if it's the *correct* one.

```c
inode_init_owner(sb->s_user_ns, root, NULL, S_IFDIR | 0755);
```

It seems that the superblock has a namespace field which I can use and everything works. This does the trick, but I still don't really understand it :)